# a-frame VR camera position goes up?

Tags: camera, position, aframe, virtual-reality

i am working on an a-frame website but i just now discovered that for some reason the camera height goes up by alot when the user presses the VR button (bottom right).
can someone explain why this happens?
i am running the website on
iphone 6
ios 11
firefox

link to the website so you can see for yourself:
https://boerenkool-met-worst.firebaseapp.com/

links to images:
https://ibb.co/cTwJK6
https://ibb.co/nEaCe6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be something with the combo of the userHeight property mixed with the position property on the camera? Maybe try to wrap the camera entity and set the userHeight to 0.

Something like this:

```
<a-entity position="0 1.6 2">
    <a-camera id="camera" user-height="0">
        <a-cursor id="cursor">
        </a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: i found the workaround with your help. instead of wrapping the camera i just put the camera on user-height 0 so now when you're not in VR the camera is on the ground but when you enter vr the position is fine.